# How to check current request resource is a page in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an `IHttpModule` implementation with a delegated method hooked to `PostAcquireRequestState`, for each HTTP Request, I would like to know **how to check if the current requested resource is a Page (aspx)** discriminating all other resources like `*.css`, `*.ico`, `*.png` and so on.

Actually I can do the following:

```
private static void OnPostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  bool isPage = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.EndsWith(".aspx");
}
```

But I would like to know if there is something different to do than hard checking with ".aspx".

Comment: What about `ashx, asmx, asx` and other server-side executable formats?

Comment: @Abel, that's the reason I would to know if there is *something different to do a hard checking against the format `".aspx"`*. Thanks for highlighting that point, since I didn't put it on my question. :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Be.St. I would like to check if the `Session` object exists when requesting a page, because when requesting another resources such an icon the `Session` seems like to be always `null`.

Comment: Is not enough to check if (Request.Session==null)?
Or are you in a situation like: "if the request is for a page check session. Then if session is null do something else do something different"?

Comment: Indeed, this is my situation. I need to check the `Session` if the request is for a Page.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do is to get a list of registered [HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httphandlerssection.aspx) and check whether they are handled by a system class. Assuming you don't name your own classes in a namespace `System.*`, this is quite foolproof:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;

Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
HttpHandlersSection handlers = (HttpHandlersSection) config
                               .GetSection("system.web/httpHandlers");

List<string> forbiddenList = new List<string>();

// next part untested:
foreach(HttpHandlerAction handler in handlers.Handlers)
{
    if(handler.Type.StartsWith("System."))
    {
        forbiddenList.Add(handler.Path);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can revert the lookup and list *all* existing handlers except those in your own (or current) domain, possibly provided some exceptions (i.e., if you want to override an existing image handler). But whatever you choose, this gives you full access to what's already registered.

---

Note: it's generally easier to do the reverse. You now seem to want to blacklist a couple of paths, but instead, if you can do whitelisting (i.e., make a list of those extensions that you *do* want to handle) you can make it yourself a lot easier.