# How to know the requested resource type [aspx page v/s static .css .js files] in ASP.Net in the Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, global-asax, page-lifecycle

In the Global.asax processing pipeline, what is the best way to detect the requested resource type? Whether the requested resource is a page, httphandler, image, css etc.

Note: I have already read this one [How to check current request resource is a page in C# ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927637/how-to-check-current-request-resource-is-a-page-in-c-sharp-asp-net) and it does not solve my issue because when routing is used to take off the .aspx extension, I lose out the means to detect the page based on the extension. [Request comes in as http://localhost:38590/Default instead of http://localhost:38590/Default.aspx]
I have enable friendly URLs turned on and I need to keep them on:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();
}
```

I am customizing the User object attached to the context in the Application_PostAuthenticate and want to apply this customization only to request that are coming in for physical .aspx pages and not for other resources like .js .css etc.

I have one observation thought - The Session object is not available for non .aspx page requests (i.e. requests for .jpg, .js etc.) in the Acquire Request State event. This gives me hope that the .Net framework has some mechanism to resolve the requested resource and I would like to use the same mechanism that the framework uses or use a derived attribute from the framework rather doing a raw string match approach on the incoming URL etc.

Comment: Show your current `Application_PostAuthenticate` event. `Session` should be available from the `HttpContext` anytime it's in a request processing pipeline.

Comment: HTTPContext.Current.User = new MyCustomPrincipal(); This is the pseudo code of my user customization. The session isn't available until Application_AcquireRequestState event.